# SQL error between referencing and references columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL and at the time I want to reference it gives me this error:

[image: Error]

The columns are exactly the same, but it insists that they are incompatible.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT(  
    product_name VARCHAR(255) COMMENT 'Product name',
    related_words VARCHAR(255) COMMENT 'Words related to the product',
    cost FLOAT(5) COMMENT 'Product cost',
    live int(1) COMMENT 'item visibility',
    measure VARCHAR(100) COMMENT 'measure of the product',
    imageURL VARCHAR(200) COMMENT 'image that holds the product',
    primary key (product_name, measure)
) DEFAULT CHARSET UTF8 COMMENT '';
```

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS_PRODUCTS(
    product_name VARCHAR(255),
    OrderNo int(10),
    FOREIGN KEY (product_name) REFERENCES PRODUCT(product_name),
    PRIMARY KEY (product_name, OrderNo)
)
```

Comment: I think that you can improve your design using an integer instead of product_name for your primary key

Comment: They are same type (`varchar(255)`) but different charset.

Comment: https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/

Comment: Add error messages as text not as image

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error (or see it). Please add the charset and engine for both tables.

Comment: I can reproduce the error if the character set for `orders_products` is utf8mb4. I guess that's your default character set in your environment. Specify the same character set for both tables, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are doing a composite primary key. Your primary key it's a composite of product_name and measure.

As I say in my comment, generally you create a numeric ID for every table and use it as primary key and later as your foreign key.